# Rolling count unique in dataframe's rows or ndarray

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation, accumulate

Given a dataframe `df`, how to calculate the rolling count of unique values through rows' direction subject to a boundary condition: **window size** = **n**?

Input data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col_0':[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
        'col_1':[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        'col_2':[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 15],
        'col_3':[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 21],
        'col_4':[7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5],
        'col_5':[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 21]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
###
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
0      7      4      2      2      7      2
1      8      5      5      6      5      6
2      9      6      8     10      7     10
3     10      7     11     14      5     14
4     11      8     14     18      7     18
5     12      9     15     21      5     21
```

Expected output (with window size = 2):

```
print(df)
###
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  rolling_nunique
0      7      4      2      2      7      2                3
1      8      5      5      6      5      6                6
2      9      6      8     10      7     10                6
3     10      7     11     14      5     14                8
4     11      8     14     18      7     18                7
5     12      9     15     21      5     21               10
```

---

For the example above with window size = 2.

- **At `window 0`'s array** we have **row[0]**.

  ```py
  [[7 4 2 2 7 2]]
  ```

  `rolling_nunique[0]` is 3 with the elements being [2, 4, 7].
- **At `window 1`'s array** we have **row[0] & row[1]**.

  ```py
  [[7 4 2 2 7 2]
  [8 5 5 6 5 6]]
  ```

  `rolling_nunique[1]` is 6 with the elements being [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].
- **At `window 2`'s array** we have **row[1] & row[2]**.

  ```py
  [[ 8  5  5  6  5  6]
  [ 9  6  8 10  7 10]]
  ```

  `rolling_nunique[2]` is 6 with the elements being [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].
- etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html), you can customize how the values are aggregated in the sliding window. To get values for all rows before the sliding window is full (i.e., emulate `min_periods=1` in [`pd.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)), we need to add some empty rows at the top. This can be done using [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [`full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html). At the end, we need to account for these added nan values by filtering them away.

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

w = 2
values = np.vstack([np.full([w-1, df.shape[1]], np.nan), df.values])
m = sliding_window_view(values, w, axis=0).reshape(len(df), -1)
unique_count = [len(np.unique(r[~np.isnan(r)])) for r in m]
df['rolling_nunique'] = unique_count
```

Result:

```
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  rolling_nunique
0      7      4      2      2      7      2                3
1      8      5      5      6      5      6                6
2      9      6      8     10      7     10                6
3     10      7     11     14      5     14                8
4     11      8     14     18      7     18                7
5     12      9     15     21      5     21               10
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it could resolve by using `sliding_window_view()` from `numpy`,
Here's the approach:

```
rolling = 2
ar = df.values # turn into np.ndarray
length = ar.shape[1]
head_arrs = np.zeros((rolling-1, rolling*length))
cuboid = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(ar, (rolling,length)).astype(float)
plane = cuboid.reshape(-1,rolling*length)

for i in range(rolling-1,0,-1):
        head_arr_l = plane[0,:i*length]
        head_arr_l = np.pad(head_arr_l.astype(float), (0,length*(rolling-i)), 'constant', constant_values=np.nan)
        head_arr_l = np.roll(head_arr_l, length*(rolling-i))
        head_arrs[i-1,:] = head_arr_l

plane = np.insert(plane, 0, head_arrs, axis=0)
df['rolling_nunique'] = pd.DataFrame(plane).nunique(axis=1)
df
###
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  rolling_nunique
0      7      4      2      2      7      2                3
1      8      5      5      6      5      6                6
2      9      6      8     10      7     10                6
3     10      7     11     14      5     14                8
4     11      8     14     18      7     18                7
5     12      9     15     21      5     21               10
```

[[reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)] numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view